# Using Query or QueryOver to join on relationships that don't exist in objects

Tags: nhibernate

This may seem like a silly title but I'm running into a small problem and I wasn't sure if there was another way around it.

I currently have the following entities:
**Location** <---> **LocationContent** --> **Container** <---> **ContainerContent** <--- **OrderLine**

The above entities relationships' are marked with the arrows.  Location can have many **LocationContent** and a **LocationContent** has a link to it's parent **Location** etc.

My problem is that whenever I need to basically join all these tables (**JoinAlias**) to restrict my result set I'm unable to because not all of the above entities have bi-directional relationships.  In some cases it doesn't make sense for me to have bidirectional relationships because the user will never access the data that way.  It really only seems to make sense when I'm querying data.

#### Are these bi-directional relationships a necessary evil for querying data with QueryOver and Query or is there another way around this that I'm not thinking about?

Comment: yes, you need to define the bi-directional relationship in order to generate the query from either end. You contradict yourself when you say the user won't access data that way, but the queries need to.

Comment: @dotjoe, When I say the user won't access the data that way I meant for example that I would never access a ContainerContent's OrderLine collection.  I would however access the ContainerContent that was related to the OrderLine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dotjoe nailed it down: you DO need those relationships.

Why do you think they are evil? they're free.

The only query method that allows freeform joins is HQL.

Comment: Well I don't think they're evil.  I was just avoiding extra relationships within my entities where they weren't necessarily needed.  Thanks for the HQL tip.  That was what I was asking.